# React-Konva Text Alignment and Wrapping not working

Tags: reactjs, canvas, konvajs

I am unable to align my text to center on my canvas, nor can I get the text to wrap to a new line when the length exceeds the length of the canvas.

```
import { Layer, Stage, Text } from 'react-konva';
render() {
return (
<Stage height={500} width={500}>
  <Layer>
    <Text fontSize={60} text="`HEYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY`"
        wrap="char" align="center" />
  </Layer>
</Stage>
)
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what results do you get?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works just fine. Width of a text is not limited by canvas size. Instead it is limited by its own `width` property.

If you don't set width it will be unlimited.

```
<Text
  fontSize={60}
  text="HEYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
  wrap="char"
  align="center"
  width={700}
/>
```

http://jsbin.com/dolegimuvi/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Hi, want to know where you find this element because I can't find a completed document for React-Konva, their website only has the Konva docuemnt

Comment: @MichaelMao what element do you mean? `react-konva` just works on top of `Konva`. Similar to how `react` works on top of DOM.

Comment: `import { Text } from 'react-konva';`